# Display only n-characters of string Asp.Net webapp in <p> element

Tags: asp.net, truncate

I'm having trouble slicing a string to a certain length and adding '...' to the end of it. This code worked within a  element but gave an error inside of a

element. I get no error in my IDE
the code:

```
<p class="card-text">
    @{
        string x = item.Info.Length > 100 ? item.Info.Substring(0, 100) : item.Info;
        x = x.Length == 100 ? x + "..." : x;
    }
    @Html.Raw(x)
</p>
```

The error:

> **NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

Comment: Is `item` not null? Is `item.Info` not null?

Comment: If I use @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Info) it displays the text but I want to truncate the result